# Ionic Native File : File.writeFile not working (file not getting created + no call back response)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have tried different available solutions but file is not getting saved and nothing happens i.e, callback functions are not getting called neither success nor error.

Solution already tried.
1. Moved polyfill.js before cordova.js in index.html
2. tried writing simple text string in txt file even txt file is not getting created
3. also changed file.dataDirectory to file.cacheDirectory.

here is code sample:

```
var fileName = Date.now().toString() + ".csv";
var that = this;
that.file
  .writeFile(that.file.cacheDirectory, fileName, csv, {
    replace: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    that.setStatus("CSV file saved as " + fileName);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    that.setStatus("Error saving CSV file.");
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your app has (or had requested) the correct permissions to the OS ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Problem was my application is in ionic 3 but when I added ionic native file plugin latest version of plugin was added (Ver. 5+). apparently there was no error no issue but on writing file no call back response was getting generated, neither success nor error. following are steps that fixed this issue for me.

1. Clear npm cache
2. add ionic native file plugin Version 4.